# self in lambda passed to free function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm confused as to why the following code works. When is self.param evaluated? Do closures feature here?

```
from collections import namedtuple

T = namedtuple("T","a b")

def validate(condition):
    t = T(1, 2)    
    return condition(t)

class C:
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param

    def test(self):
        condition = lambda v: v.a==1 and v.b==2 if self.param else v.b!=2
        print(validate(condition))

c = C(True)
c.test()
```

Should I be writing:

```
condition = lambda v, param=self.param: v.a==1 and v.b==2 if param else v.b!=2
```

and if so why?

Answer (score 0):

Because lambdas in Python are "proper" closures, any external variable references will be evaluated when the lambda is invoked, not when it is defined.